# $\sin2(x) - \tan(x) = 0$ , solve for $-180\le x\le 180$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I have been unable to solve the following question,

If $$\sin(2x) - \tan(x) = 0$$

Find $x$ , $-\pi\le x\le \pi$

So far my workings have been
Use following identity:

$$\sin(2x) = 2\sin(x)\cos(x)\\2\sin(x)\cos(x) - \tan(x) = 0\\2\sin(x)\cos(x) - \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)} = 0\\
2\frac{\sin(x)\cos(x)}{1} - \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)} = 0$$

Then cross multiply to give :

$$-\sin x+((2\cos(x)\sin(x))\cos(x))/\cos(x) = 0$$

$$-\sin x+(2\cos^2(x)\sin(x))/ \cos(x) = 0$$

However, I have been unable to get any further.

If someone could help me find a solution to this question it would be very much appreciated.Thank you.

Comment: You forgot to keep dividing by $cos(x)$ which you can simplify because $\pi/2$ isn't allowed. Also, you can factor $sin(x)$, so you get a product equals 0. Now either of the factor must be 0. Solving for each factor is ok.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The equation we want to solve is $$\sin(2x)-\tan(x)$$
You deduced correctly that we now have to solve $$2\sin(x)\cos(x)-\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}=0$$ which we can rewrite to $$2\sin(x)\cos(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}$$
or $$2\sin(x)\cos(x)^2=\sin(x)$$
Now, either $\sin(x)=0$ (in which case $x\in\{-180,0,180\}$, given that $x\in[-180,180]$), or we may divide both sides by $\sin(x)$ to get
$$2\cos(x)^2=1$$ So $\cos(x)=\pm\sqrt{\frac12}=\pm\frac12\sqrt{2}$, of which we know the solutions to be $x\in\{-135,-45,45,135\}$, and therefore the final solution is $$x\in\{-180,-135,-45,0,45,135,180\}$$

Comment: I follow everything you have described apart from that sqrt (1/2) = -135,-45,45,135 . my calculator shows arc cos of sqrt (0.5) to be 45, now can i find the 135 ? thankyou

Comment: @Calculon, try to sketch the graph in the interval $[-180,180]$, or draw the unit circle. Can you find where $\cos(x)=\pm\tfrac12\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: Thank you this has been a tremendous help, the penny has finally dropped !

Answer (score 4):

Notice, $$\sin 2x-\tan x=0$$
 $$\frac{2\tan x}{1+\tan^2x}-\tan x=0$$
$$\tan x\left(\frac{1-\tan^2 x}{1+\tan^2x}\right)=0$$
$$\color{blue}{\tan x\cos 2x=0}$$
Now, solving for $x$,
$$\tan x=0\iff x=n\cdot 180^\circ$$
where $n$ is any integer

For given interval $[-180^\circ, 180^\circ]$, setting $n=-1, 0, 1 $, one should get  $$\color{blue}{x=-180^\circ, 0, 180^\circ}$$

or $$\cos 2x=0\iff 2x=(2n-1)\cdot 90^\circ\ \ $$$$or \ \ x=(2n-1)\cdot 45^\circ$$
where $n$ is any integer

For given interval $[-180^\circ, 180^\circ]$, setting $n=-1, 0, 1, 2 $, one should get  $$\color{blue}{x=-135^\circ, -45^\circ, 45^\circ, 135^\circ}$$

hence, the complete solution is 
$$\color{red}{x\in\{-180^\circ, -135^\circ, -45^\circ, 0, 45^\circ, 135^\circ, 180^\circ\}}$$

Comment: Thank you that makes lots of sense, I appreciate you help.

Answer (score 1):

Once you got to 
$$2\sin(x)\cos(x) - \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)} = 0$$ 
you can pull out a factor of $\sin (x)$ to get 
$$\sin(x)\left[2\cos(x)- \frac{1}{\cos(x)}\right]$$ 
Now, either $\sin(x) = 0$ or $2\cos(x)- \frac{1}{\cos(x)} = 0$. For $\sin(x) = 0$, we have $-180$, $0$, and $180$. For $2\cos(x)- \frac{1}{\cos(x)} = 0$, we can multiply through by $\cos(x)$ to get $2\cos^2(x)-1 = 0$. Solving gives $$\cos(x) = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$$ 
so x = -45 and 45.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.  Also, you overlooked the possibility that a square root could be a negative number, so you did not find all the solutions.

Comment: Thank you this has certainly helped me gain a better understanding.